# How to make video responsive using video tag in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-video

I want to make video responsive in html.For that i'm using video tag.
Following is the code i've tried.

```
<video controls autoplay="true" loop class="video_travel">
    <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="video/video.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="video/video.ogv" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

Now when i opened the website which contains the video in mobile phone , what i'm getting is there will be a play button , but can't play anything.Please help..

Answer (score 1):

You can use "max-width:100%" check snippet below..

```css
video {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<video controls autoplay loop class="video_travel">
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE.ogv" type="video/ogg"  />
</video>
```

Comment: Yes, tried this now i can play the video , but can't do autoplay.

Answer (score 1):

Use Css Property-

```
video {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this

```
 video {
  width: 100%    !important;
  height: auto   !important;
}
```